# Code to calucate all combonations of HEX color values

Tags: colors, hex

I would like to create a complete list of all the combinations of HEX color values (000000 - FFFFFF).

Is there code or a script to produce all of these rather quickly? all 16 million colors?

I don't even know how to approach this.

Comment: They're just numbers.  Count from zero to 0xffffff

Comment: i was looking tou output a list like this:
000000,
000001, 000002,000003, etc all the way to ffffff

Comment: Are you looking for the HTML color names also?  For example: #8B0000 is "Dark Red" and #008000 is "Green"

Comment: no no names, just hex numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done in any language.  But here's python for example:

```
for i in range(0x1000000):
   print '%06x,' % i,
```